# Firestore security rules - how are reads counted for exists, get, getAfter?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) gives the details of how are reads counted when using the functions exists, get and getAfter within security rules.
But what does these exactly mean:

> You are only charged one read per dependent document even if your rules refer to that document more than once.

- So if I use 2 get in the same rule, it is only 1 read
- But what if I use get and getAfter in the same rule? Am I billed 2 reads or only 1 as it is the same document?

> You are charged for rule evaluation only once per request

Does this mean that if I use get on the same document but from different rules in the same batch, it is 1 read in total instead of 1 per get? Same question for getAfter

EDIT2: moved additional question to a new post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The billing is per document read.  It doesn't matter if you use `get` or `getAfter` or both.  It is still just one "dependent document".  The rules for batches are evaluated simultaneously per batch, as they have to be atomic.  1 batch == 1 request.  You will not be charged for multiple gets of the same document, as only 1 read is required for the atomic evaluation of the rules for the entire batch.

Comment: This,Is,Awesome, I added one more question regarding get in batches

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's customary not to change the question after it's been answered.  Also it's off topic to ask multiple questions per post.  Please post your additional question separately, and I suggest also showing an example of code and rules that you're working with.